# Failed to Map Path '/doc'. server.map path

Tags: asp.net

If I run the site using the internal Visual Studio web server, I get the failed to map path error.

Comment: @sornamuki some more details would really help us give you answer..

Comment: Server.MapPath("/") returns the physical path to the root of the domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the application)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a security problem.

I assume you use Vistual Studio 2008 and Vista or Windows Seven.

Launch Visual Studio with the administrator right, and the problem should disappear.